# Why is my table background color not working in htm5?

Tags: html, background, html-table

I'm putting a background on a table in HTML5. I cannot seem to get the background to display. I am using the table bgcolor="FF0000 tag, but it still won't work. I've tried using the CSS, and that won't work either. Help?

Comment: I use the <> in there. It will not show up in the question if I put them around the tag.

Comment: I'd just do: style="background-color:blue" or whatever color.

Comment: <table bgcolor="#00FF00"> Have you tried another color?

Answer (score 1):

```css
table.bg-red {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table class="bg-red" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```